# Proteger Requisições HTTP com Android

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho uma aplicação em Android, que requisitas arquivos Servlet ou JSP que retornam JSON.

Por exemplo, no meu aplicativo o usuário faz login e pode adicionar pedidos, quando adiciona pedidos, o mesmo é adicionado via Servlet no formato JSON, então ele requisita uma URL http.

Eu geralmente passo uma chave junto via POST e no arquivo de Servlet verifico se a chave esta certa e permito a requisição.

Pergunto: existe uma forma mais eficaz e segura?

Answer (score -1):

Existe uma forma melhor. Implementa  JWT   https://jwt.io/ no seu server. assim você envia o TOKEN sempre que fizer uma requisição.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhor compreendida se você explicar o que o JWT faz de forma que o autor da pergunta possa aplicar o que foi sugerido.